# What means random field in "Conditional Random Field"

Tags: conditional-random-field

I have studied about CRF but the popular papers and tutorials have not describe the philosophy of CRF.  I see the terms "Field", "Random Field" and "Conditional" from terminological aspect. But the papers, blogs and forums did not define the intuitive view for the programmer or computer engineer.I want to find out the point of view which that CRF see world.

Comment: "We will use the term random field to refer to a particular distribution
among those defined by an undirected model."

Source: Sutton, C., & McCallum, A. (2012). An introduction to conditional random fields. p. 274 Link: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/csutton/publications/crftut-fnt.pdf